# What's the point of Java's (this Collection)?

Tags: java, python

So, out of curiosity, I decided to find out what happens when you add a list to itself. Since a list is just an object, and you can have a list of objects in Java, I thought it should be possible.

```
List<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(a);
```

This does indeed compile and run just fine. So I decided to see what happens when I try to print it.

```
List<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(a);
System.out.println(a);
```

This outputs:

```
[(this Collection)]
```

So clearly the java devs thought of this exact scenario, and added a special case to handle it. Well it's not particularly useful (at least I don't see where it's handy), apart from maybe preventing a crash due to infinite recursion (printing a tries to print a which contains a and so on...).

Except this only really works with one list:

```
List<Object> a = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object> b = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(b);
b.add(a);
System.out.println(a);
```

This results in a StackOverflow. So clearly the handling is not generic enough to handle arbitrary reference loops - it only works when you add a list to itself. So why bother with it? What's the point?

PS: Python for instance seems to have it handled in general.

```
>>> l = []
>>> l += [l]
>>> l
[[...]]
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a += [b]
>>> b += [a]
>>> a
[[[...]]]
```

I read the `[[[...]]]]` notation as `a` is a list that contains a list that contains a.

Comment: Looks like Python flatterns the list while Java keeps the List as it is. Your second example fails for that reason.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by flatten the list?

Comment: *So why bother with it? What's the point?* ... it is just a choice made. I dont see pressing technical reasons here for anything. Probably the assumption was: that super simply mistake, we can detect and handle gracefully. Anything more complex, well, your problem. In other words: imho, this is purely about opinions, which renders your question off topic.

Comment: @hoodakaushal, to flatten a list is to de-nest it; f/e, to change `[[1,2],[3,4]]` to `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: From the [documentation of Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html): “Some collection operations which perform recursive traversal of the collection may fail with an exception for self-referential instances where the collection directly or indirectly contains itself. This includes the `clone()`, `equals()`, `hashCode()` and `toString()` methods. Implementations may optionally handle the self-referential scenario, however most current implementations do not do so.”

Comment: @VGR I think it's perfectly reasonable implementations either handling self-referential-ness, or not, I'm just curious why is half-assed. But thanks for the link.

Comment: BTW, see also [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design), particularly the answer focusing on the Help Center guidance that "[y]ou should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face". If you already know how to avoid the only "actual problem" involved, it's not a *practical* question (one about how to better practice software development).

Comment: Probably because the handling you’re seeing was easy to implement.  But keeping a set of previously encountered elements in an entire graph of collections would add nontrivial overhead.

Comment: It's much harder (if it's possible at all, actually) to handle more complicated cases of recursion with just a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(this Collection)` is implemented in `AbstractCollection#toString`, which iterates over itself and checks if any of the members are `this`. https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/47ee6c00d27c/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#l457

`[...]` is produced by `repr` of `listobject` and others by a check to `Py_ReprEnter`, which tracks the reentry of objects using a thread local dict: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Objects/object.c#L1971

You could try to patch the AbstractCollection implementation to use a thread local dictionary — tracking all collections and their elements that are currently being toString'd in the current thread. It might work, or it might not. As a guess: the Python interpreter is by and large single-threaded, which might allow it to get away with certain tricks better, and the Java issues you'll run into might only be apparent with concurrent modifications that would otherwise be safe. Better to not make guarantees of avoiding infinite recursion that cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score -5):

Actually there is no such thing named this Collection...

You can get this code from `AbstractCollection.java`

```
    /**
     * Returns a string representation of this collection.  The string
     * representation consists of a list of the collection's elements in the
     * order they are returned by its iterator, enclosed in square brackets
     * ({@code "[]"}).  Adjacent elements are separated by the characters
     * {@code ", "} (comma and space).  Elements are converted to strings as
     * by {@link String#valueOf(Object)}.
     *
     * @return a string representation of this collection
     */
    public String toString() {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (;;) {
            E e = it.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (! it.hasNext())
                return sb.append(']').toString();
            sb.append(',').append(' ');
        }
    }
```

So that is just a way in making this array's toString being more readable for humen.

Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Did you actually try to run the code I shared?

Comment: so what did you mean?

Comment: are you meaning println an arraylist does not call its toString()?

Comment: Or you are meaning class ArrayList does not get toString() from class 
 AbstractCollection?

Comment: Or you mean the code I show above cannot explain why it stackoverflow(because a.toString() calls b.toString() and b.toString() calls a.toString())?

Comment: Don't worry, if you really cannot understand my words you can still use python.dear python have already thought it throught out how to make every code,ugly or not, right or false, run well.

Comment: @hoodakaushal as fully explained as I can...I really hope you can get it.If you have anymore questions please ask.

Comment: What I meant was your answer doesn't really address the observed behavior when a self-referential collection is converted to string

Comment: @hoodakaushal then what do you think about this line `sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);` ?

Comment: Well, because my point was why does it happen this way, simply pointing to the relevant code is not really helpful. I'm more curious about why it's there in the first place.

Comment: @hoodakaushal Because in this way it will use far less memory. If you want to track it fully, you must memory each layer of each list. I'm not so familiar to python nor knowing about how it does it, but I do think it be a great memory waste, as few people will really do this in code, and they can override it if they really want.